# i want sum of 4 textfield in 5th one on change of values of above 4 fields in flutter

Tags: flutter

this is code. for 4 textfield and one for adding those values also take switch case for getting the values from the label of textfield but didn't get any output. my switch case also work but didn't get any output in totalSum variable.

this is code. for 4 textfield and one for adding those values also take switch case for getting the values from the label of textfield but didn't get any output. my switch case also work but didn't get any output in totalSum variable.

````
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _AmountEdit();
}
class _AmountEdit extends State<AddAmount> {
  final amount = new TextEditingController();
  final amount1 = new TextEditingController();
  final amount2 = new TextEditingController();
  final amount3 = new TextEditingController();
  final amount4 = new TextEditingController();
  final total = new TextEditingController();

  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _focusNode1 = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _focusNode2 = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _focusNode3 = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _focusNode4 = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _focusNode5 = FocusNode();

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      print("Has focus: ${_focusNode.hasFocus}");
      if (_focusNode.hasFocus == false) {
        print(test);
      }
      if (test.contains(",00")) {
        print("perfect amount");
      } else {
        String finalAmount = test + append;
        print("the final amount ${finalAmount}");
        amount.text = finalAmount;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  String append = ",00";
  String test;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Retrieve Text Input'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextBox1(
            controllerText: amount,
            focusNode: _focusNode,
            label: "amount",
          ),
          TextBox1(
            controllerText: amount1,
            focusNode: _focusNode1,
            label: "amount1",
          ),
          TextBox1(
            controllerText: amount2,
            focusNode: _focusNode2,
            label: "amount2",
          ),
          TextBox1(
            controllerText: amount3,
            focusNode: _focusNode3,
            label: "amount3",
          ),
          TextBox1(
            controllerText: amount4,
            focusNode: _focusNode4,
            label: "amount4",
          ),
          TextBox1(
            controllerText: total,
            focusNode: _focusNode5,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TextBox1 extends StatefulWidget {
  var controllerText;
  var focusNode;
  String label;

  TextBox1({this.controllerText, this.focusNode, this.label});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TextBox();
}

class _TextBox extends State<TextBox1> {
  String test;
  int test1;
  String append = ",00";
  String finalAmount;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (widget.focusNode.hasFocus == false) {
        print(test);
        if (test == "") {
          finalAmount = "";
        } else {
          if (test.contains(",")) {
          } else {
            finalAmount = test + append;
            widget.controllerText.text = finalAmount;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return TextField(
        onChanged: (value) {

          print("widget label ${widget.label}");

          print("onchangecallback");
          test = value;
          print("printng value ${value}");

          test1 = int.parse(value);
          sum(value, widget.label);
//          print("printing test1 ${test1}");
        },
//        inputFormatters: [
//          WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
//          CurrencyInputFormatter(),
//        ],
        controller: widget.controllerText,
        focusNode: widget.focusNode,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          disabledBorder:
              OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        ));
  }

  dynamic a;
  dynamic b;
  dynamic c;
  dynamic d;
  dynamic e;
  dynamic totalSum;

  sum(value, type) {
//    print("print value ${widget.controllerText}");
//    print("print amount text field ${value}");
    switch (type) {
      case "amount":
        {
          setState(() {});

          a = value;
          print("value of A ${a}");
        }
        break;

      case "amount1":
        {setState(() {});
          b = value;
          print("value of B ${b}");
        }
        break;

      case "amount2":
        {setState(() {});
          c = value;
          print("value of C ${c}");
        }
        break;

      case "amount3":
        {setState(() {});
          d = value;
          print("value of D ${d}");
        }
        break;

      case "amount4":
        {setState(() {});
          e = value;
          print("value of E ${e}");
        }
        break;

    }
    print("value of A outside the switch ${a}");
    print("value of B outside the switch ${b}");
  totalSum = a + b + c + d + e;
    print("this is total ${totalSum}");
  }
}```
````

Comment: in switch case i got null values for all dynamic variable a,b,c,d...

Answer (score 0):

Why not using TextEditingController.fromValue controller?

```
    new TextField(
      controller: new TextEditingController.fromValue(
          new TextEditingValue(
              text: field1,
              selection:
      onChanged: (content) {
        setState(() {
        sum = field1+field2+field3+field4;
      });
      },
      onTap: (() {}),
      onSubmitted: ((s) {
        setState(() {
        });
      }),
    ),
```